# Вывод изображения на экран Windows

Tags: python, c++, изображения, desktop

Возникла необходимость нахождения картинки на экране. Окна открытого на панели задач по возможности видно быть не должно. Скорее всего это будет наиболее реализуемо на C++. Но код прошу сделать в виде функции чтоб потом в DLL закинуть и из Python через ctypes вызывать функцию как-то так

```
import ctypes

mydll = ctypes.WinDLL("...\mydll.dll")
mydll.ShowImage("...\image.bmp")
```

Возможно ли это реализовать. Если да, то подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, так как в c++ не шарю. Заранее спасибо

Comment: попробуйте написать pyqt приложение. может получится [скрыть из таскбара](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-how-to-hide-app-from-taskbar/) и даже [убрать рамку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960298/pyqt-frameless-window-at-specified-coordinates)